# Can we set the foreground color on TileTemplateType.TileWideImageAndText01 to a colour of my choosing

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

Just wondering if there is any way to set the foreground colour of the text on a TileWideAndText01 tile template or are we limited to dark or light only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limited to dark or light only.  From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.startscreen.secondarytile.foregroundtext.aspx):

> Only two text colors are available—default dark and default light—and
>   are set by Windows. Choose the text color that will look best with
>   your choice of background color and the opacity of your logo image.